# Can I have a different Org Wide Email address in Production and Sandbox

Tags: email

I'm trying to get Email to Case set up in Sandbox to do some testing and keep running into a situation where a response email to the user (who sent the original email to case) has a From: email address that reflects the org wide email setting in our Production Org instead of the one defined in the Sandbox.  Consequently the users return email goes to an email that doesn't exist in the Sandbox.  Weird!  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple org wide email addresses linked to multiple profiles. So that users can select each of them according to their requirement.

Here you can see from where to access.

[image]

And then define one for your organization.

[image]

You can have different set of org-wide addresses for each org.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the settings in your Case Auto-Response rules in the Sandbox?

Comment: Yep, already checked that... Pulling my Sandbox into IDE to find out where that hidden instance is

Comment: Found it!  Turns out that this (rogue) email address was under Setup>Communities>All Communities>Manage>Administration>Emails>Sender!  - Exactly where I would think to look for it when trying to get email to case working!